# Show custom response message in Spring boot JPA pagable controller

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pageable

I have a pageable controller like following. I have used the filter which will give HttpServletResponse depending on the condition. And i want to show all user if only HttpServletResponse status code is 200. Or else i want to show custom message.

```
@GetMapping("/user/all")
 @JsonView(Views.UserDetailView.class)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAllUsers(Pageable pageable,HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (response.getStatus() == 200) 
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userRepository.findAll(pageable));
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new JsonResponse("some error msg to show"),
                HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
}
```

sample of my user repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {

}
```

JsonResponse Dto

```
public class JsonResponse {
    private String message;
    private HttpStatus httpStatus;
    //getter setter and constructor..
}
```

The problem with above implementation is that if the filter gives response code other than 200, then the response from the controller won't show custom error message. It only show the response code. Filter can produce various kinds of error codes such as 402 and 406.
How can i show the custom error message?

> ps: All other controllers works fine except the controller with
>   Pageable object

Comment: There is no response yet, so your check doesn't do anything.

Comment: refer to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status

Comment: @M.Deinum There is a response, and the response is from the filter that i have added

Comment: No there  isn't. The response is written by the controller. Yes there is a response but it doesn't contain anything and will at that moment always be 200. If you block/change it in a filter then write a custom response there, not in a downstream controller.

Comment: All other controller are working fine except the controller with Pageable object. And i am getting the expected response code from the filter. In other controller without Pageable object, it is showing error message as well.

Comment: use `@ExceptionHandler`

Comment: start here https://www.baeldung.com/global-error-handler-in-a-spring-rest-api

Comment: @WonChulHeo that link didn't help me

Comment: I forgot to use `@JsonView({Views.UserDetailView.class})` in my JsonRespone Dto.